# how to make select field required when using onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, select, onchange

I in my html form the select field required option is not working while i am using on change event to get value. The form is being submitted while the department field is selected but employee field is not selected. Below is my code,

```
</br><label for="Department" id="CustomID">
    Department
</label>
<select name="Department" id="Department" class="form-control" onChange="getemployee(this.value);" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
    <?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from department");
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
      {?>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['department']);?>">
        <?php echo htmlentities($row['department']);?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>

</select>
</br><label for="employee" id="CustomID">
    Employee
</label>
<select name="employee" class="form-control" id="employee" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Employee</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what you can do is, in your ```getemployee``` method check if value is empty or not. Because I think required attribute works only when form is submitted.

Comment: At least one value would be selected as long as you see it on the Client, in a normal (old and lame) form submission. If you're using AJAX (which you should be) you usually send the property and value via JSON to the Server. Everything should be tested on Client and Server Side.

Comment: yes, i am using ajax to get the value, could you please suggest me how to solve it. here is the code,<script>
function getemployee(val) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get_employee.php",
  data:'department='+val,
  success: function(data){
    $("#employee").html(data);
  }
  });
}
</script>

Comment: First, check what value is coming in id `Department`. user alert/console to see the value.